# HTML5 video tilted or must use flash?

Tags: flash, video, html5-video, tilt

I want to use for new website project video player in tilted mode.

For example in 30° angle ( 1/6 radian )

Is it possible to do with use of JS/HTML5 video tag or I do have to use flash video player?

If I do have to use flash, can you recommend any free player with this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS transforms to rotate the video container:

```
video{
   -moz-transform:rotate(30deg);
   -webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);
   -o-transform:rotate(30deg);
   -ms-transform:rotate(30deg);
}
```